# Page not found in admin panel after applying patch 6788 and editing config.xml

Tags: patches, admin-panel, magento-1.9.2.0, supee-6788

After installing the patch I tried to change the `config.xml` of the extension. The extension has two config.xml files. In below you can find the revision I made, but still I get page not found error.

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <gremlincustom>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Junaidbhura_Gremlincustom</module>
                <frontName>gremlincustom</frontName>
            </args>
        </gremlincustom>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

To

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <gremlincustom after="Mage_Adminhtml">Junaidbhura_Gremlincustom_Adminhtml</gremlincustom>
                    <frontName>gremlincustom</frontName>
                </modules> 
            </args> 
        </adminhtml> 
    </routers> 
</admin>
```

and

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <gremlinreports>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Junaidbhura_Gremlinreports</module>
                <frontName>gremlinreports</frontName>
            </args>
        </gremlinreports>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

To

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <gremlinreports after="Mage_Adminhtml">Junaidbhura_Gremlinreports_Adminhtml</gremlinreports>
                    <frontName>gremlinreports</frontName>
                </modules> 
            </args> 
        </adminhtml> 
    </routers> 
</admin>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might also need to adjust the calls of your admin controller(s).
I ran into the same issue today where the system entry in the adminhtml.xml still referenced to the old frontname.
Note the change in `<action>`.

Old:

```
<config>
    <menu>
        <system>
            <children>
                <your_module translate="title" module="your_module">
                    <title>Your Title</title>
                    <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                    <action>your_module/your_controller</action>
                </your_module>
            </children>
        </system>
    </menu>
...
</config>
```

New:

```
<config>
    <menu>
        <system>
            <children>
                <your_module translate="title" module="your_module">
                    <title>Your Title</title>
                    <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                    <action>adminhtml/your_controller</action>
                </your_module>
            </children>
        </system>
    </menu>
...
</config>
```

Edit: There can also be other places in the code where you need to adapt the controller calls, depending on your extensions.

Comment: By other places in code, do you mean still in xml files? Because I edited the action parts but still same error :(

Comment: Actually it could be somewhere in the system.xml or mostly other controller files.